# How do I count how often each value occurs in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I have simulated 10 die rolls and stored the numbers in a single vector called `data`. I need to sort the 10 numbers either in order, or in a way which lets my program know how many of each die face there is. A friend suggested I use an array which steps through the 10 numbers and adds a digit to one of the six columns depending on which die face it is, but I'm unsure of how to do this.

```
void Game::sort_hands()
{
    vector<int> data;
    for(int i = 0; i < player.hand.size(); ++i){
        data.push_back(player.hand[i]);
        data.push_back(opponent.oppHand[i]);        
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i){
        cout<<data[i]<<"  ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your friend has a good and straightforward idea, that will execute in O(n) time, which is perfect.  Get him/her to explain it better to you, as they seem on the right track.

Comment: Sounds like a marvelous idea your friend had. Much better than using a sort routine.

Comment: This is definitely a beginners question. I would suggest you do research on your own rather than asking (it shouldn't take too long). But your friend is definitely on the right track. You already have the code to iterate thought your vector (the for loop) you just need check the value increment the counters for that face. I'd love to give you the code since I know the answer, but I am sure you can solve this on your own if you make an array and use the stored value to determine the index of the counter in the array to increment.

Answer (score -1):

Well if you are looking for someone to give you answers to your homework, i would say this is the wrong place for that, but we can point you in the right direction. There are many common and easy to implement sorting algorithms, but be aware that the overhead associated with many sorting algorithms may not be worth it considering the size of your data set. Look into algorithms, as well as understand the capabilities of the data structure you are using, the std::vector.